# Python Loops, Functions, Etc

Tags: python, function, loops

I made a miler per gallon program and I have it all working there's just a few things I would like to add that i'm not too sure how. The things i'm trying to add are when entering a number 0 or negative when it asks you for how many miles were driven and how many gallons of gas were used it will give you an error that says "Please enter a number greater then 0" and has them re-enter the number. Another thing i'm trying to do is loop it so the same questions will be asked 4 times and each time it will print out their information that is being calculated in the code as if there are 4 cars you can check the MPG each time the program is ran.

Another thing I was wondering is if I wanted to have this same code but in functions how would I go about this? The different functions would be like main ( ), printWelcome ( ), getMiles ( ) , getGallons ( ) , calcMpg ( ), printMpg ( ), and rateMpg ( ).

This is what I currently have:

```
print ('Miles Per Gallon Program')
print ('\n')


milesDrove = float( input( "How many miles were driven?" ) )
gallonsOfGasUsed = float(input( "How many gallons of gas were used?" ) )
milesPerGallon = milesDrove / gallonsOfGasUsed
print ('\n')
print("The MPG is: " + str(milesPerGallon) )

if milesPerGallon < 12:
    print ("Poor mpg")
elif milesPerGallon < 19:
    print ("Fair mpg")
elif milesPerGallon < 26:
    print ("Good mpg")
else:
    print ("Excellent mpg.")\
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def printWelcome():
    print ('Welcome to the Miles per Gallon program')
def getMiles():
    miles = float(input('Enter the miles you have drove: '))
    return miles
def getGallons():
    gallons = float(input('Enter the gallons of gas you used: '))
    return gallons
def printMpg(milespergallon):
    print ('Your MPG is: ', str(milespergallon))
def calcMpg(miles, gallons):
    mpg = miles / gallons
    return mpg
def rateMpg(mpg):
    if mpg < 12:
        print ("Poor mpg")
    elif mpg < 19:
         print ("Fair mpg")
    elif mpg < 26:
         print ("Good mpg")
    else:
         print ("Excellent mpg")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    printWelcome()
    print('\n')
    miles = getMiles()
    if miles <= 0:
        print('The number of miles cannot be negative or zero. Enter a positive number')
        miles = getMiles()
    gallons = getGallons()
    if gallons <= 0:
        print('The gallons of gas used has to be positive')
        gallons = getGallons()
    print('\n')
    mpg = calcMpg(miles, gallons)
    printMpg(mpg)
    print('\n')
    rateMpg(mpg)
```

The loop to repeat the above process can be put inside main(), where the function starts. It will ask to enter the numbers n times for n cars and will calculate, rate and mpg for all inputs

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get an input from the user, and retry if the input was not validated is as simple as declaring an initial invalid value and looping until the user inputs a valid value:

```
milesDrove = -1
while milesDrove <= 0:
   try:
       milesDrove = float( input( "How many miles were driven?" ) )
       if milesDrove <= 0:
           print("Please enter a number greater then 0")
   except:
       print("Please enter a number greater then 0")
```

Given the basic level of your questions I asume you just started a python course at your college/school. In the example above i used exception handling, because the call to float() can raise an exception if the input is not a number (the user can never be trusted, but depends on what level of validation you are confortable with).

Looping N times:

```
for i in range(4):
    print("Calculate the MPG for car #%d" % i + 1)
    milesDrove = float( input( "How many miles were driven?" ) )
    gallonsOfGasUsed = float(input( "How many gallons of gas were used?" ) )
    milesPerGallon = milesDrove / gallonsOfGasUsed
    print ('\n')
    print("The MPG is: " + str(milesPerGallon) )

    if milesPerGallon < 12:
        print ("Poor mpg")
    elif milesPerGallon < 19:
        print ("Fair mpg")
    elif milesPerGallon < 26:
        print ("Good mpg")
    else:
        print ("Excellent mpg.")\
```

Finally, regarding your question about functions, having functions that do all their job in one line is kind of overkill. In your case, most of them will just return a single value. In general, although the python interpreter will run your code even if its not inside a function(this is not c or java, we don´t really need a main function) usually people declare the starting point of their scripts as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

Deciding when to declare a function or not can be difficult to a beginer. As a general rule you should declare a function whenever that piece of code is called multiple times form other parts of your code or if the work that is done by such function is very well defined (for instance a function that calculates the fibonnaci sum)